# Replace all string values with another within a project - C#

Tags: c#, string, forms, visual-studio, replace

In my current project I want to implement a checkbox that, if checked, replaces all strings in labels, tabs, etc. currently being shown on a form with a different string.

For example, If checked, all instances of the word "car" would change to the word "truck" all through out the program.

I'd rather not go through a do a .replace on every single string in the code. I was wondering if there was some way to "intercept" output strings and replace them on the fly; something like making a string-listener. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you show your code or GUI?

Comment: @GrantWinney yea makes me feel like i Got The World On A String.....

Comment: Use localization features for this.

Comment: @RichardHein that would be the optimal way of doing this, unfortunately I'm working on a large project that didn't set out to use localization. Any implementation would have to occur during runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no GUI/WinForms program but this would be my personal approach. Add all of these UI elements to a `List<T>` in the forms constructor. Then in the "replace box checked event handler" you can just iterate over the list applying the same change to all the items. It's by no means a perfect solution but it does mean you only have to statically reference each of the items once. After they're in the list you can operate on all of them very easily.

Comment: This is actually a pretty good implementation. Thanks!